# Referencing DataRows by column name in a LINQ query, then filter via mapping with another dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Excel sheet that contains columns and a list of column mappings.

```
List<Mapping> _mapping
```

Mapping is a class that contains two strings

```
public class Mapping
{
    public string ExcelColumn { get; set; } //the excel column name
    public string MapTo { get; set; } //the column in sql database that it maps to
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to marry the two data sets similar to a SQL `WHERE [field1] IN [field2]` clause.  But I'm having two problems:

- Cannot apply [] indexing to Class
- EnumerableRowCollection contains no definition for Field

**Code:**

```
var allActivity = GetActivity();

using (DataTable excelData = GetExcelDataAsTable()) //get datatable representation of EXCEL SHEET
{
    var excelDataRows = excelData.AsEnumerable();

    //do this for each field mapped
    foreach(Mapping fieldMapping in _mapping)
    {
        var result = from activity in allActivity //where clause contains errors
                     where activity[fieldMapping.MapTo].Contains(excelDataRows.Field<string>(fieldMapping.ExcelColumn))
                     select activity;
    }
}
```

Here's `GetActivity()`, it returns an IEnumerable

```
private IEnumerable<TradeActivity> GetActivity()
```

Comment: `activity` is no longer an array or collection, so you cannot apply `[]` operator, unless `TradeActivity` has some kind of operator overriding.

Comment: @DatVM I can only reference field names via dot notation... How to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

First, we need the ability to reference a class property by string name.  Add this to the class

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null); }
    set { this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(this, value, null); }
}
```

Need to isolate one of the datasets:

```
var excelColumn = excelData.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[fieldMapping.ExcelColumn]);
```

Then do the where clause:

```
var result = from activity in allActivity
             where excelColumn.Contains(activity[fieldMapping.MapTo])
             select activity;
```